# Transform hex to short and long

Tags: javascript, long-integer, short

How can I transform a value like `OxFF` to short and long types. is there a standard function for this use?

Comment: What do you mean short and long types?  In Javascript, there is only a single [numeric type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-754).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp Use the radix.

Comment: I think this link can help you upto some extent http://www.softcomplex.com/forum/viewthread_4321/ but then you have to YOURSELF to know if the converted no. is a short or long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript only knows about [numbers](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) which are floats.

You can use `parseInt` to parse that string into an integer.
It really is going to be a `float` but without a fraction.

---

Either pass the radix `16` or let JavaScript autodetect it:

```
parseInt("0xFF", 16)
parseInt("0xFF")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/wVRh2/

Comment: Did you try this?  `parseInt("0xFF", 10); // => 0, not 255`.  You will need to drop off the `0x` and parse base 16, or drop the radix altogether, which is ususally a no-no.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Parsing `0xFF` to the base of `10` results in `0`. Leave away the radix parameter or pass `16` and you will get the correct result: http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/wVRh2/